# MSSQL query to find items missing from multiple baskets?

Tags: sql-server

Quite a simple problem and it can be done programmatically but I am hoping to use pure MSSQL query to accomplish this.

My Task:
A suggestion list has been compiled with many items.
Now I want to determine which shopping basket(s) do not have all suggested items And which items they are missing. I want to return the shopping basket id and the item id.

The database so far:

Table: **tblSuggestions**

| SuggestionId (Integer) | ItemId (Integer) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 4 | 71 |
| 5 | 441 |
| 6 | 721 |
| 7 | 762 |

Table: **tblCustomer**

| CustomerId (Integer) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

Table: **tblShoppingBasket**

| CustomerId (Integer) | ItemId (Integer) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 1 | 31 |
| 1 | 441 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 2 | 762 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 3 | 71 |
| 3 | 441 |
| 3 | 721 |
| 3 | 762 |
| 4 | 762 |
| 5 | 441 |
| 5 | 721 |

It's a very simple database with the minimal details but this is a pet project for myself.

Is there an MSSQL query to return which shopping baskets are missing one or more items from the suggestions AND which item ids?

Edit: Fixed table layout

Edit: Added sample data. There are no primary/foreign keys and no insert/delete triggers.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: From a maintenance point of view, it is a bad idea to mix SINGULAR and PLURAL names for tables. I prefer Plural because there are more than one of that thing in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this using the `EXCEPT` statement, ie generate the complete universe first by creating the Cartesian product of Customer and Suggestions, then do the set exception to return the difference.  An example using your data:

```
USE tempdb
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblSuggestions;

CREATE TABLE tblSuggestions (
    SuggestionId    INT NOT NULL,
    ItemId          INT NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY ( SuggestionId, ItemId )
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblCustomer;

CREATE TABLE tblCustomer (
    CustomerId  INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( CustomerId )
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblShoppingBasket;

CREATE TABLE tblShoppingBasket (
    CustomerId  INT NOT NULL,
    ItemId      INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( CustomerId, ItemId )
);


INSERT INTO tblSuggestions
VALUES
    ( 1, 1   ),
    ( 2, 13  ),
    ( 3, 31  ),
    ( 4, 71  ),
    ( 5, 441 ),
    ( 6, 721 ),
    ( 7, 762 )


INSERT INTO tblCustomer
VALUES
    ( 1 ),
    ( 2 ),
    ( 3 ),
    ( 4 ),
    ( 5 )
    

INSERT INTO tblShoppingBasket
VALUES
    ( 1, 1   ),
    ( 1, 13  ),
    ( 1, 31  ),
    ( 1, 441 ),
    ( 2, 13  ),
    ( 2, 31  ),
    ( 2, 762 ),
    ( 3, 31  ),
    ( 3, 71  ),
    ( 3, 441 ),
    ( 3, 721 ),
    ( 3, 762 ),
    ( 4, 762 ),
    ( 5, 441 ),
    ( 5, 721 )
GO


SELECT * FROM tblSuggestions 
SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE CustomerId = 1
SELECT * FROM tblShoppingBasket WHERE CustomerId = 1


SELECT c.CustomerId, s.ItemId
FROM tblCustomer c
    CROSS JOIN tblSuggestions s

EXCEPT

SELECT CustomerId, ItemId
FROM tblShoppingBasket;
```

I have included DDL and INSERT statements here which you should also do usually do help you get a good answer.  You mention returning the shoppingBasketId but your data does not have one.

My results:

[image: results]

So you can see here CustomerId 1 does not have suggestions 71, 721 and 762 and so on.

For very large datasets then this could be quite expensive and you may wish to break it up a bit depending, but I imagine you would get to millions of rows and items before this was a problem on a well-configured modern database platform.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the items per customerId, and compare that with the count in suggestions.
Something like this

```
select t.CustomerID, 
       t.ItemID,
       t.ItemCountPerCustomer
from   ( select sb.*,
                (select count(1) from tblShoppingBasket sb2 where sb2.CustomerID = sb.CustomerID group by sb2.CustomerID) as ItemCountPerCustomer
         from   tblShoppingBasket sb
       ) t  
where  t.ItemCountPerCustomer <> (select count(1) from tblSuggestions )
```

Comment: It's a good idea however it doesn't tell me precisely which ItemIds are not in every basket and which customer is missing them.

Comment: Your tables not having primary keys is making this difficult

Comment: I didn't think they would help but if you want to add some then please do. I'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross join on suggestions and customers. Then LEFT join that to the baskets and display the ones that arent matched

```
SELECT
    Every.CustomerId, Every.ItemId 
FROM
( SELECT * FROM tblCustomer,tblSuggestions ) AS Every
LEFT JOIN tblShoppingBasket ON tblShoppingBasket.CustomerId=Every.CustomerId AND tblShoppingBasket.ItemId=Every.ItemId
WHERE tblShoppingBasket.CustomerId IS NULL
ORDER BY Every.CustomerId, Every.ItemId
```